# Current Image in a ViewSwitcher

Tags: android, viewswitcher

is there a possibility to get the name/reference/id of the current displayed image in a ViewSwitcher?

```
switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);

[...]

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
       Log.d(TAG, "tell me please, how to get the name/reference/id/etc of the currently displayed image, so i can start a specific action relating to the current image");
       return false;
}
```

Thanks!

Tobias

Comment: @mango: ok but the question is how to detect the currently displayed image, so i can start a specific action relating to the current image? I cannot add code in comment, so see below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the 'edit' button above to make changes to your question post.

As for your question, if you're using a `ViewSwitcher`, I think you can do with some sort of indicator to tell you which screen (which `ViewGroup`) is being displayed. Like an `int` or `boolean` that you're modifying when switch commands are called.

Comment: ...use an "indicator", OK that's a workaround ;)  Thank you!  BTW: OK, I will change the question post.

Answer (score 28):

In `ViewSwitcher` you can only have at `max 2 views` (Which are images in your case).

To get current view by `getCurrentView()` method

Or to get the index of current visible item by `getDisplayedChild()` method, which can be either `0` or `1`

Comment: This is definitely the best answer and the proper answer to the question asked.